# How the other person's messages disappeared and it's showing as Facebook user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

How the other person's messages disappeared and it's showing as Facebook user?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When an account gets deleted permanently, and if you have had a conversation with that account earlier, it shows as Facebook user.

It simply means other person's account has been deleted permanently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  So if I deleted my account permanently,  all the messages I've sent before will be deleted from other people accounts?

Comment: Your name will be deleted. Messages will be deleted just deleting the account. Before deleting your account just report the conversation as spam, hopefully it will delete the messages.

Answer (score -1):

There can be a few things that happen:

1. The user de-activated or deleted their account.
2. Facebook banned or removed their account.
3. The user blocked your account.